# CSS - Elements stacking vertically not horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have a row with seven small images and a heading which I need to stack horizontally but they're stacking vertically. This is how it looks -

[image: Vertical not horizontal]

I'm sure this is really simple but I'm stumped. I'm using reset & skeleton grid. This is the relevant code -

**HTML**

```
<section id="products">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="twelve columns agencyproducts">
                    <h2>WHAT PRODUCT ARE YOU INTERESTED IN?</h2>
                    <img src="images/production.png" alt="Production" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                    <h4>2K / 4K PRODUCTION</h4>
                    <img src="images/post-production.png" alt="Post-Production" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                    <h4>POST PRODUCTION</h4>
                    <img src="images/animation.png" alt="Animation" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                    <h4>2D / 3D ANIMATION</h4>
                    <img src="images/ADHOC.png" alt="ADHOC" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                    <h4>ADHOC</h4>
                    <img src="images/interactive.png" alt="Interactive" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                    <h4>INTERACTIVE & PERSONALISED</h4>
                    <img src="images/tv-adverts.png" alt="TV ADVERTS" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                    <h4>TV ADVERTS</h4>
                    <img src="images/360.png" alt="360 Video and VR" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
                    <h4>360 VIDEO & VIRTUAL REALITY</h4>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
section#products {
    height: 700px;
    max-width: 100%

}

.row {
    height: 350px;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.agencyproducts {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

}

.agencyproducts img {

    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
    top: 50%;

}

.agencyproducts h4 {

    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10px;

}
```

Comment: `<h2>, <h4>` are block elements and will take full available width if not limited in css

Comment: I don't see a single `display: inline-block` / `display: inline` anywhere ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `h4` tags which you re using as captions are block elements, which means, their width is 100% by default. Also, you have nothing that associates/unifies them with the images they belong to.

The common way nowadays is to use a `figure`tag to wrap image and text, and put the text into a `figcaption`tag inside that figure tag. Then apply `text-align: center;` and `display: inline-block;` to the `figure` tag to center image and text inside and allow them to appear next to each other:

```css
figure {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/cac">
  <figcaption>
    This is an image
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/cac">
  <figcaption>
    This is an image with a longer caption
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80/cac">
  <figcaption>
    This is an image
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Can I put some width and height rules on 'figure'? At the minute the text is running in one line and taking too much space up along the row - I need some of it to stack.

Comment: sure - just add `max-width`. I edited my snippet, you see the result there. I also added `vertical-align-top`and a smaller margin than the default. Just try different CSS settings on figure, `figure img` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Images and Headers by default have `display` set to block, meaning they are on their own lines. `float` used to be the preferred way of achieving single-line display for block elements but it should be avoided as `float` has some weird behaviors. Instead we now use `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline;` - apply this to the elements you want on a single line and it will make it so!

just example (not copying your code - just simple example script):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="one.png" class="inlineImg" />
    <img src="two.png" class="inlineImg" />
    <img src="three.png" class="inlineImg" /> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inlineImg {display: inline;}
```

this will display the images on a single line (providing the div is big enough)

Answer (score 0):

```
.agencyproducts {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And you could put the main title outside of row div

That should all make them horizontal. You may need to add some padding to separate the items tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the img- and h4-Tags with a div-Tag and make it float.

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <img src="images/production.png" alt="Production" style="width:50px;height:50px;">
 <h4>2K / 4K PRODUCTION</h4>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
 float: left;
}
```

Don't forget to unfloat afterwards.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `float` it's becoming less and less used for this - can be done using `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

The H4 will make them 'stack' vertically. Best to enclose each image and heading in it's own block or span, and on that div/span use " display: block; float: left;".

Answer (score 0):

Basicly the h4 element has automaticly a wifth of 100%, you can check this easily with the inspection tool of your browser.

The easiest was is to put a div arround h and img element

```
<div class="containerIcon">
  //img element
  //h element
</div>

.conainterIcon {
  display: block;
  width: 13%, //So they all fit in one line
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the image and the title below in a div, and float them all to the left. Like so—

```css
.bullet-point { float: left; }

.clear-float { clear: both; }
```

```html
<div class="bullet-point">
  <img src="images/production.png" alt="Production">
  <h4>2K / 4K PRODUCTION</h4>
</div>

<div class="bullet-point">
  <img src="images/production.png" alt="Production">
  <h4>2K / 4K PRODUCTION</h4>
</div>
.
.
.and so on
<div class="clear-float"></div>
```